If $p:E\to B$ is an $n$-sheeted covering space with $E\cong B$, why must $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ be infinite?
This is a past qualifying exam question.

Let $B$ be path connected and suppose there is an $n$-sheeted covering space $p:E\to B$ such that $E$ is homeomorphic to $B$, with $n \geq 2$. Show that $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ must be infinite.

Here is my attempt:
Let $e_0 \in p^{-1}(b)$. Since $B$ is path connected and $p$ is an $n$-sheeted covering map, then the index of $p_\ast(\pi_1(E, e_0))$ in $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ is exactly $n$. However, since $E$ is homeomorphic to $B$, then $p_\ast(\pi_1(E,e_0))\cong p_\ast(\pi_1(B,b_0))$. Then since a covering map induces an injection on $\pi_1$, we can identify $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ with a subgroup of itself of index $n$. By LaGrange's theorem, we thus have
$$| \pi_1(B,b_0) | = n |\pi_1 (B,b_0)|,$$
but since $n \geq 2$, it follows that $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ must have infinite cardinality.
Question: The problem assumes that $E$ is homeomorphic to $B$, but my argument only uses that they are homotopy equivalent. Did I make an error, or is the assumption stronger than what is needed?

Groups can't have size 0...

Your proof is fine, if phrased a little oddly. It all boils down to the fact a finite group can't have a proper subgroup isomorphic to the whole group.

When a condition is "too strong" is a little arbitrary. Homotopy equivalence would suffice here, but so, too, would assuming that $E$ is path-connected and $\pi_1 E \cong \pi_1 B$, or for that matter $|\pi_1 E| = |\pi_1 B|$ (or even $n |\pi_1 E| \neq |\pi_1 B|$), but you probably wouldn't phrase the result that way.

I think this have to be proved by contradiction. Then it seems more naturally.

Have a confidence bro..

Your proof is fine.
I have the other approach that I made.
First, If we assume that $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ is finite group, $\pi_1(E, e_0)$ have to be finite because of the homeomorphism. $H_1(B)$ is isomorphic to $\pi(B, e_0)/[\pi_1(B, e_0), \pi_1(B, e_0)]$, and $$0 \to [\pi_1(E, e_0), \pi_1(E, e_0)] \to \pi_1(E, e_0) \to H_1(E) \to 0$$ is exact. $k × |p_*[\pi_1(E, e_0), \pi_1(E, e_0)]|$ $=$ $n|\pi_1(E, e_0)|$, $k$ $=$ $|H_1(B)|$.
So, $|H_1(E)| = n × |H_1(B)| = n × H_1(E)$. homology group is not empty, so contradiction.
I think your proof is right. Also, more simple than this. Here is just an example to use more strong condition, which is using the homeomorphism.

This doesn't make sense to me. How are you concluding $|H_1(E)|=n|H_1(B)|$?

Remember that $E$ is homeomorphic to $B$...

Ok, where are you using that to establish the above equality? Even your own exactness equation contradicts it. You've written $k|G'|=n|G|$, where $G=\pi_1(E)$. This implies $|G|/|G'|=k/n$. Your exact sequence then shows $|H_1(E)|=k/n=|H_1(B)|/n$.
